# Quotient rings in formal power series

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I'm trying to find all prime ideals in the formal power series ring $k[[x]]$, where $k$ is a field.

I think I've managed to show that all ideals are of the form $\langle x^n \rangle$, $n>0$, i.e. generated by a single element.

I now want to use the condition that an ideal, $I \subset R$ is prime iff $R/I$ is an integral domain. So am I right in thinking that $k[[x]] / \langle x^n \rangle$ is the set of cosets $f + \langle x^n \rangle$ where f is a polynomial of degree less than n? It would be great if I could have some help on showing that this is then an integral domain?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, every coset has one unique element that is a polynomial of degree less than $n$. In general, $k[[x]]/\langle x^n\rangle$ is not an integral domain, only for specific $n$.

Comment: Okay thanks! Why does the polynomial have to be unique? Is it correct that this is then isomorphic to the integers modulo n?

Comment: If $\deg f < n$ and $\deg g < n$, then also $\deg (f-g) < n$. If further $x^n \mid (f-g)$, from degree/order considerations it follows that $f-g = 0$. $k[[x]]/\langle x^n\rangle$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$. It is an $n$-dimensional $k$-vector space (and $k$-algebra). If it is an integral domain, it does in particular contain no nilpotent elements (except $0$). What does that say about $n$?

Comment: Ah yes I see that. So there are no elements $f + <x^n>$ s.t $(f+<x^n>)^k = f^k + <x^n> = 0 + <x^n>$ for some k. So for example the $<x^3>$ case is not an integral domain because taking $f=x^2$ gives $f^2 = 0$? Am I thinking of this the right way? I'm not quite sure how we can get a condition on n, thanks

Comment: It looks like you're on the right track. What about $\langle x^2\rangle$?

Comment: Well in that case $f = x$ gives $(x + <x^2>)^2 = x^2 + <x^2> = 0 + <x^2>$ so that is also not an integral domain? Thank you for all your help!

Comment: And in general $(x+\langle x^n\rangle)^n = \langle x^n\rangle$, so the only prime ideal is $\langle x\rangle$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: and $0$ (since $k[[x]]$) is a domain). But these are all of them

Comment: @user115654 Right. I often forget that one when dealing with principal ideal domains, since $0$ is not a prime element, and of course the prime ideals are the ideals of the form $(p)$ for primes $p$ then, aren't they?

Comment: Right, in a PID every ideal is principal, so the primes are precisely of the form $(p)$ for $p$ a prime element. Why do you say that $0$ is not a prime element though (in a domain)? Perhaps a matter of taste, but I see no reason not to include it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've correctly found that the nontrivial ideals of $k[[x]]$ are of the form $(x^n)$ for positive integers $n$.

Since we know $k[[x]]$ is a domain and that its ideals form a chain, we are guaranteed that $(0)$ and the maximal ideal $(x)$ are prime.

The only question then is whether or not $(x^n)$ is prime for powers $n>1$. But they are clearly not prime since for every such $n$, $x,x^{n-1}\notin (x^n)$, but their product is in $(x^n)$.